# avoiding obstacles with IR and Ultrasonic sensor in addition to laser data

Tags: mobile-robot, ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, 2d-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have turtlebot3 with imu, LIDAR and ultrasonic/infrared sensors. I want to build a map autonomously, and then navigate on this map, avoid obstacles such as glass, mirrored metal chair legs.

1. First question. For example, at first, I want to build a map autonomously. Am I supposed to use ultrasonic sensors here at this stage, for mapping? Should i give sensor_msgs/Range to mapping packages, such as gmapping, cartographer and others? Or its only for move_base?
2. Second question. At this picture, on the right, http://wiki.ros.org/move_base?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=overview_tf.png
   I see sensor_topics(sensor_msgs/LaserScan, sensor_msgs/PointCloud), but i dont understand, how it is supposed to give sensor_msgs/Range to move_base package?

Is there any detailed tutorials or examples about how to use data from laser and ultrasonic/ir sensors together to avoid obstacles?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329720/avoiding-obstacles-with-ir-and-ultrasonic-sensor-in-addition-to-laser-data/) by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2019-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Usually mapping packages only take into account laser information and it is common place to ignore ultrasonic/infrared sensors during this stage. If you want the obstacles detected by your ultrasonic/infrared sensors to appear on the map, then you would need to feed them to the mapping process. For instance [cartographer](https://google-cartographer-ros.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ros_api.html) accepts laser readings, imu and point clouds as input. You could transform your range messages to point cloud and pass it to cartographer.
2. The image that you mention is a bit old, move_base uses costmap_2d to generate the global and local costmaps. costmap_2d can accept many different types of data sources and luckily there is a plugin for range sensors that you can use: [range_sensor_layer](http://wiki.ros.org/range_sensor_layer)

I don't know about a detailed tutorial to use laser and ultrasonic/ir sensors together. But if you can get your system working with the laser, then it is quite straight forward to add range sensors.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2019-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1